# Updating one-to-many with Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to build a modified role system that has the following class/relationship structure:

Project
ProjectRole
Employee

where

ProjectEmployee maps the three entities together.

I have a one-to-many mapping from Project to ProjectEmployee and a reference mapping from ProjectEmployee to Project.

I can add new ProjectEmployee's just fine (which means my Create activities are fine as well), but I want to constrain the relationship to have only one entry per Employee.  This affects the logic of my Update activities.

In hacking this together, I am attempting to empty the Project.ProjectEmployees (by setting the value to a new List) and then adding a new instance of ProjectEmployee with the appropriate role, etc.

In doing this, I get an error that is related to setting Project.ProjectEmployees to an empty List.

"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ProjectId', table 'AppDB.dbo.ProjectEmployees'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated."

If I remove the line that news up the List, the subsequent records get added, but then I'm staring at too many records per employee.

Here's my Project -> ProjectEmployees mapping:

```
mapping.HasMany<ProjectEmployee>(x => x.ProjectEmployees)    
    .Cascade.All()
    .WithKeyColumn("ProjectId");
```

And the mapping in ProjectEmployee -> Project:

```
mapping.References(x => x.Project, "ProjectId");
```

Should be simple right?

For what it's worth, I also added a method to my Project class called AddProjectEmployee that searches for the Employee in question, removes his ProjectEmployee if he exists, then adds the new ProjectEmployee.  I get the same error when I call this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [cross-posted on the Fluent NHibernate group](http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/b5c3eb713f2f82f3) and answered there by Hudson Akridge. As Hudson said, the solution is to use `Clear()` on the collection as that allows NHibernate to track the changes (whereas newing up the collection causes the property to reference an instance NH doesn't know about).

Comment: Thanks Stuart.  I saw the response on the FNH group as well, and the Clear did in fact resolve my issue.